# CSS Content Position in IE

Tags: jquery, css

I have a basic "username" textbox. This textbox can be seen here: http://68.71.136.106/test.htm

In Chrome, the TextBox looks how I want it to look.The watermark is positioned properly, and when a user types text, the text is positioned properly. However, in IE, When I type text in the box, the text is positioned properly. But, the watermark is not positioned properly.  It looks like it is 2 or 3 pixels lower than vertical center.  I am using the JQuery Watermark plugin: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/. My code looks like this:

```
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/scripts/jquery.watermark.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background-color:#E6E7E8; padding:40px;">
        <div>Username</div>
        <div><input id="usernameField" type="text" 
            style="background-position:183px 332px; background-image:url(/images.png); height:15px; width:146px; border:0px none; padding:5px 10px 0px 10px; color:#A6A8AB; font-size:10pt; font-family:Verdana;" /></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#usernameField").watermark("USERNAME");
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Is there a way for me to fix this appropriately? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The watermarks don't like inline CSS styles, try putting them in a style block and it should fix the problem.

Comment: They actually are in a style block. I just put them inline for the sake of brevity in this question.

Comment: oh I apologize, I didn't copy the css exactly. On a side-note, padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px seems to fix it.